# Error in Copying Elements from the Base Sheet to a New Sheet Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting this error :

> **Run-time error '1004': Copy Method of Worksheet Class failed**

We're trying to create new sheets from a base sheet. This code needs to copy the base sheet's elements and put them in a new sheet and works perfectly on my co-worker's computer but not on mine I don't know why. I've checked several related questions but there is no use for me.

```
    Sub Otomatik_CategoryMenuleriniOlustur()
    Dim ToplamCategoryMenuSayisi As String
    Dim Pos As Long

    Sheets("Otomatik_ID_Category").Select

    Range("C8:C1000000").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    AktifSatir = ActiveCell.Row

    ToplamCategoryMenuSayisi = AktifSatir - 9

    'MsgBox ToplamCategoryMenuSayisi

    Range("A1").Select

    Call forEachWs_Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonunu_Bul

    'MsgBox "Urunler Category Orj Sayfasýnýn Sayýsý Konumu : " & Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonu

    j = 0

    For i = 9 To ToplamCategoryMenuSayisi + 8


            Pos = InStr(Cells(i, 3), "Pizza")
            If Pos > 0 Then

                            'MsgBox Cells(i, 3) & " Hücresinin " & Pos & " pozisyonunda Pizza Bulundu. Sayfasý Eklenmeyecek"
                            j = j + 1


                       Else

                            Sheets("Urunler Category Orj").Copy After:=Sheets(Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonu + j)
                            j = j + 1

                            EklenenSayfa = ActiveSheet.Name
                            'MsgBox EklenenSayfa
                            SayfaAdi = Sheets("Otomatik_ID_Category").Cells(i, 3).Text
                            'MsgBox SayfaAdi
                            'Sheets("Urunler Category Orj (2)").Select
                            Sheets(EklenenSayfa).Name = SayfaAdi

                            Cells(7, 4).Value = SayfaAdi & ".png"

                            Cells(7, 2).Value = Sheets("Otomatik_ID_Category").Cells(i, 1).Text

                            Cells(7, 1).Value = (i - 7) * 1000


            End If
                'HucreIcerigi = Search




    Next i

    Sheets("Otomatik_ID_Category").Select

End Sub
```

-

The highlighted line is this :

```
Sheets("Urunler Category Orj").Copy After:=Sheets(Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonu + j)
```

The excel file if needed : [Tablo Yapisi Macro BA.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l10tbzqxgl7ttx/Tablo%20Yapisi%20Macro%20BA.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: can you upload full code?.

Comment: @TheGridLock I've uploaded the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because you have not assigned a value to:

```
Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonu
```

Comment: "Call forEachWs_Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonunu_Bul" works for that and gets value for "Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonu "

Comment: @EdwardMordrake  I don't see the value getting passed back to `Otomatik_CategoryMenuleriniOlustur`

Comment: I tried to manually assign a value to "Urunler_Category_Orj_Sayfa_Pozisyonu" but there is no use. I've uploaded the excel file if you want to take a look. Thank you!